# How to get content using ajax.get or ajax.load when the external content is genareted by ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get contents from an external HTML file but most of the content in that file are generated via client side so when i call that file i don't get the contents i expect.

here is the code i'm using:

```
  $.ajax({
        url: '*******************',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (res) {

            $("#target").html(res.responseText);


        }
    });
```

thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

The javascript ( ajax call, etc) of the external html file isn't execute.

Maybe loading the external html in a iframe, will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using something like an iframe, wherein you include the page you are currently retrieving via AJAX in a frame inside your "parent" page?

Comment: thanks guys, but with the iframe can i select dom elements using jquery when the external file is on an another domain? i.e. yahoo.com